# Recommended Services Architecture in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Currently, I have all services inside a services directory and multiple components are depending on them and also one service has dependency on another service and so on. The dependency graph of services and components would look crazy. Due to this in certain cases, when trying to inject one service into another, I get a DI Error. Following is a sample of one of my situation:

```
import {stuff} from 'stuffs';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService
{   
    getData(): Observable<string>{
        return this.http.get(url).map(v => v.json());
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class SomeService
{   
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService){

    }
}

@Component()
export class SomeComponent
{
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
        private someService: SomeService){

    }
}
```

I did not find any recommended pattern for organizing services so after much code written I am asking for some guidance that can point me to right direction and refactor it.

Comment: this is not enough information. What kind of DI error do you get? I have an angular 2 application where services inject other services, but if you create the dreaded diamond of inheritance it will break down (unless they've finally fixed that, I haven't upgraded to rc1 yet)

Comment: what error do you get ? the scenario that you show here should work. Its better post the full error message in these cases, you will get more effective help like that

Comment: @AngularUniversity I am not able to reproduce the error at the moment. But can I at least get a hint on recommended practice for organizing services in an angular 2 app?

Comment: have a look at the services cookbook https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html, also you jave this course  https://angular-university.io/course/angular2-http let me know in the feedback form if it helps

Comment: I was under the impression that Angular 2 services can be like a wrapper for http or it can also be used as backend (for lack of better term) for the components so that all the logic can be taken from the component to the their services e.g. `./popover.component.ts`, `./popover.service.ts`. Am I wrong to think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a styling guide on angular 2 site: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#application-structure

> Do be descriptive with file names and keep the contents of the file to exactly one component.
>
> Avoid files with multiple components, multiple services, or a mixture.
>
> Why? We spend less time hunting and pecking for code, and become more efficient. If this means we want longer file names, then so be it.

But also on the small note it says:

> There are deviations of the 1 per file rule when we have a set of very small features that are all related to each other, as they are still easily identifiable.

There is also a *Overall Folder and File Structure* guide and much more in which you might find interesting stuff.

And take a look at this answer for services depending on other services: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979228/5706293

Comment: I guess because it's a link-only answer which is discouraged. The answer should contain the relevant parts directly. You could cite the relevant parts from the style guide directly in your answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Oh, will do then. Thanks for the tip!