# No Provider for HttpService in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've got following "constellation" in my angular 2 / ionic 2 project.

```
Component1 -> Service1 -> Service3
Component2 -> Service2 -> Service3
```

(where -> means something like "using" or "calling")

Without injecting the Service3 in the providers array of the components, I always face the error

```
No Provider for Service3
```

Is there a way to inject services into services in angular 2 without having to inject all of them in the components? Respectively how to manage dependencies without having to explicitly list all of them in the component?

```
import {Service1} from  '../../../providers/service1';
import {Service2} from  '../../../providers/Service3';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '...',
    providers: [Service1, Service3]}) // <= here I would like to not list Service2

export class Component1 {
}
```

I tried to inject the service in the service as described in [Inject services in another service angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979194/inject-services-in-another-service-angular-2) and didn't worked

Of couse, as long as my project stay small, there is no big deal listing all services dependencies in the components but that is not really scalable.

Comment: Are those services like singletons? Then you may consider listing all of them in the `providers` array of the root component or in the `bootstrap` call.

Comment: Yes, or at least in my example Service3 should be a singleton. That is actually an acceptable solution to have them listed in the root component, so I only have to list them once. Thx for the answer and idea.

Comment: In Angular every injected service is a singleton by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was solved by @rinukkusu. Instead of inject many times the service in many places, he proposed to inject all these "shared" services (like Service3 in my example) in the root of the application.

I still then need to list all services dependencies aka at least include once a service in a component, but at least I don't have to duplicate my code.

So in app.ts

```
import {Service2} from  '../../../providers/service2';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
providers: [Service2]
})
```

And for example a service (like Service1 in my example)

```
import {Service2} from  './service2';

@Injectable()
export class Service1 {

constructor(private service2:Service2) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The injection works hierarchically inside components, so if you want a service to be consumed in the same hierarchy level, it service needs to be provided above that level. In your case you need to provide this `Service3` in the application bootstrap.